# Problem with Serializable, CompilerGenerated

Tags: serialization, compilation

I recently had some problems with a code I was working with in Virtual Studio, below [Serializable, CompilerGenerated] line. I never did any work with that, so I don't quite understand it or how to solve the problem. The code:

```
    [Serializable, CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c
{
    public static readonly BioFuelElement.<>c<>9 = new BioFuelElement.<>c();

internal string <.cctor>b__10_0(KeyValuePair<SimHashes, string> x) =>
    x.Value;

internal object <.cctor>b__10_1(KeyValuePair<SimHashes, string> x) =>
    x.Key;
}
```

The first problem already start with the "{", as it says it is an invalid token. Then it goes with <>c and everything that has the same character, stating that it don't exist in the actual context. I'm quite sure it has nothing to do with lib or references, since I'm using the original code references and files. I just need help to understand the situation and figure out a way to solve it.

Comment: Language tag is needed.

Comment: No, it don't have any relation with language, and the main code don't have any language definition at all.